# Java EE: run a method when the .war is deployed

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I wrote a program that retrieves mails from a SMTP server. I need to start the server first, then users can get infos using REST API.

How can I run a method to start SMTP server (port 25) as soon as the .war is deployed by Tomcat?

I tried something like this:

```
   @WebListener
public class InitializeListner implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public final void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
        SMTPServer smtp_server = SMTPServer.getInstance();
        smtp_server.start();

    }
```

But it does not work and throws:

```
GRAVE: Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de l'application (application listener) 

com.smtp.server.Initializer$InitializeListner
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.smtp.server.Initializer$InitializeListner
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.smtp.server.Initializer$InitializeListner.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
```

Thank you.

edit: this is my actual code

```
public class SMTPServer extends Wiser
{
    private SMTPServer()
    {}

    private static SMTPServer SMTPServerInstance = null;

    public static synchronized SMTPServer getInstance()
    {           
        if (SMTPServerInstance == null)
        {   
            SMTPServerInstance = new SMTPServer();
            SMTPServerInstance.setPort(25);
            SMTPServerInstance.setHostname("localhost");
        }
        return SMTPServerInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message indicates that `InitializeListner` is missing a no-param constructor. How about showing the actual code?

Comment: You're missing the default constructor of your listener.

Comment: @aribeiro no, even though I added public InitializeListner(){} it throws the same error

Comment: @aribeiro ok, I found that I mispelled the class name, thank you very much